# Shorten where clauses

Tags: c#, linq

I have multiple tables which are combined with a members table on a one to one basis, the two columns I want to extract are the name from the members table and the test from the test table.
The test column is nvarchar() and has the possible entries of "P", "F", null, "", a Partial score such as (26.5) or a decimal number below 100. The following code almost does the job but it looks clunky with so many where clauses.
Also the output is ordered descending but lists double digit number after single numbers such as :
9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 91.4, 8.9, 8.8, 8.8, 86.3, 7.9...etc it seems to descend the numbers on the first digit.

```
    var tests = from t in dc1.testLevels                           
       join m in dc1.Members
       on t.testCode equals m.memCode
       where !t.Final.Equals("P") &&   // previous year pass                    
             !t.Final.Equals("F")&&   // previous year fail
             !t.Final.Equals(null)&&    // null values
             !t.Final.Equals("") &&    // empty value
             !t.Final.Contains("(")    // partial value ie..(26)
     select new {Member = m.MemName, Current = Convert.ToDecimal(t.Final)};

     var outTest = from tr in tests
                   orderby tr.Current descending
                   select new { Member  = tr.Member, Current = trCurrent};

      dgv1.DataSource = outTest;
```

Comment: The descending order is because the value is treated as a string instead of a number. See if you can convert it before ordering.

Comment: You could put the strings you are checking in a list and do `list.Contains(t.Final)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to only get the results that are decimal numbers only. Instead of blacklisting it to remove what you aren't looking for, I would instead whitelist it.

I think it would be easier to convert it to fluid notation so that you can create a `Where` clause that would look for only decimal numbers:

```
var tests = dc1.testLevels
.Where (t => {decimal dec; return decimal.TryParse(t.Final, out dec);})
.Join(dc1.Members, t => t.testCode, m => m.memCode,
    (t,m) => new { Member = m.memCode, Current = Convert.ToDecimal(t.Final) })
.OrderByDescending (x => x.Current);
```

Also notice that this allows you to put your `OrderBy` clause at the end which will order your results numerically and not alphabetically like you were doing before.

**EDIT**

After some further thought, I worked this out in query notation like you have it. Also note how the `orderby` clause has changed:

```
decimal deci;
var tests = from t in dc1.testLevels                           
   let IsDecimal = decimal.TryParse(t.Final, out deci)
   where IsDecimal == true
   join m in dc1.Members
   on t.testCode equals m.memCode
   orderby Convert.ToDecimal(t.Final) descending
   select new {Member = m.MemName, Current = Convert.ToDecimal(t.Final)};
```

**EDIT**

Since those solution will not work in Linq-To-SQL you are limited to what you can do.  The solution that the commenters to your question have given is this:

```
var ignoreList = new List<string>
{
    "P",
    "F",
    null,
    ""             
};

var tests = from t in dc1.testLevels                           
   join m in dc1.Members
   on t.testCode equals m.memCode
   where !ignoreList.Contains(t.Final)
   where !t.Final.Contains("(")    // partial value ie..(26)
    orderby Convert.ToDecimal(t.Final) descending
 select new {Member = m.MemName, Current = Convert.ToDecimal(t.Final)};
```

Comment: Will that where clause work if it is a linq to sql or similar type thing?

Comment: @Chris, the OP has a `Convert.ToDecimal` which indicates to me that it's at least not Entity Framework.  If it's Linq-To-Sql though, I'm not so sure. My guess is that the TryParse wouldn't work there.

Comment: The first block gave this error:
A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

The second block threw an exception with this reason :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Additional information: Method 'Boolean TryParse(System.String, System.Decimal ByRef)' has no supported translation to SQL.

But nice try anyway,thanks

Comment: I seem to have worked out the orderby problem by adding a second query which gives the correct output:

         var outTest = from tr in tests
                       orderby tr.Current descending
                       select new { tr.Member, tr.Current};
            try
            {
               dgv1.DataSource = outTest;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(“no data available” + ex);
            }
          dgv1.DataSource = outTest;

but this still leaves the clumsy looking where clauses.

Comment: @nigs, OK, you've discovered that TryParse will not work because you're using Ling-to-Sql.  The comments to your original question recommend another way to format your where clause; I'll include that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry @Brad still no joy got this exception this time:
exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: @nigs, that sounds like the `Convert.ToDecimal` is trying to convert something that is not a number, which means the `Where` clause is not completely filtering out all non-numerical values. You need to NOT to a conversion ToDecimal to see what data is returned to figure out if the Where clause is completely working. Then, you need to figure out if one or both ToDecimals are failing.

Comment: @Brad, I've edited the code above and now that gives the desired results, it just picks numbers from 99.9 to 0.0 and shows them in descending order. so the where clauses cover all entries that are not decimal numbers.